# doubts on the sum of 2 unsigned vectors and his output (his vector lenght) VHDL

Tags: vector, vhdl, unsigned, twos-complement

I have to solve this problem for my university course:

> write in VHDL a circuit which, based on the control signal C, dives
>   the operations shown in the table and also stores the result in a
>   register sensitive to the falling edge.
>   `C='0' OUT= A+B`;    `C='1' OUT= A-B`. Use only std_logic and std_logic_vector statements. A and B are 8-bit vectors.

Ok, I'll post my soluction and after I'll post my doubts.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity fulladder is
    port( a,b,cin: in std_logic;
          s,cout: out std_logic);
end fulladder;
architecture FA of fulladder is
    signal p,g: std_logic;
begin
    p<= a xor b;
    g<= a and b;
    s<= p xor cin;
    cout<= g or (p and cin);
end FA;

entity ripplecarry8bit is
    port(a,b:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         cin: in std_logic;
         cout: out std_logic;
         s: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));         
end ripplecarry8bit;
architecture RC8 of ripplecarry8bit is
    signal c: std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    component fulladder is
        port(a,b,cin: in std_logic;
             cout,s: out std_logic);
    end component;             
    begin
        fa0: fulladder port map(a(0),b(0),cin,c(0),s(0));
        fa1: fulladder port map(a(1),b(1),c(0),c(1),s(1));
        fa2: fulladder port map(a(2),b(2),c(1),c(2),s(2));
        fa3: fulladder port map(a(3),b(3),c(2),c(3),s(3));
        fa4: fulladder port map(a(4),b(4),c(3),c(4),s(4));
        fa5: fulladder port map(a(5),b(5),c(4),c(5),s(5));
        fa6: fulladder port map(a(6),b(6),c(5),c(6),s(6));
        fa7: fulladder port map(a(7),b(7),c(6),cout,s(7));
end RC8;

entity ripplecarry9bit is
    port(a,b:in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
         cin: in std_logic;
         cout: out std_logic;
         s: out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0));         
end ripplecarry9bit;
architecture RC9 of ripplecarry9bit is
    signal c: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    component fulladder is
        port(a,b,cin: in std_logic;
             cout,s: out std_logic);
    end component;             
    begin
        fa0: fulladder port map(a(0),b(0),cin,c(0),s(0));
        fa1: fulladder port map(a(1),b(1),c(0),c(1),s(1));
        fa2: fulladder port map(a(2),b(2),c(1),c(2),s(2));
        fa3: fulladder port map(a(3),b(3),c(2),c(3),s(3));
        fa4: fulladder port map(a(4),b(4),c(3),c(4),s(4));
        fa5: fulladder port map(a(5),b(5),c(4),c(5),s(5));
        fa6: fulladder port map(a(6),b(6),c(5),c(6),s(6));
        fa7: fulladder port map(a(7),b(7),c(6),c(7),s(7));
        fa8: fulladder port map(a(8),b(8),c(7),cout,s(8));
end RC9;

entity complement is
    port(a: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         b: out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0));
end complement;
architecture COM of complement is
    signal temp: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    component ripplecarry8bit is
        port(a,b: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
             cin: in bit;
             cout: out bit;
             s: out bit_vector(7 downto 0));
    end component;
begin
    temp<= not a;
    rc: ripplecarry8bit port map(temp, "00000001", '0', b(8), b(7 downto 0));
end COM;

entity register is
    port( d: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
          clk, clear: in std_logic;
          q: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0));
end register;
architecture R of register is
    begin
        process(clk, clear)
            begin
                if clear='1' then
                    q<="000000000";
                elsif clock'event and clock='0' then
                    q<=d;
                end if;
       end process;
end R;

entity exam is
    port( A,B: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          clk, clear: in std_logic;
          OUT: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0));
end exam;
architecture E of exam is
    signal compB, AA, BB: std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
    signal SUM, SUB, O: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    component complement is
        port(a: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
             b: out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0));
    end component;
    component ripplecarry9bit is
        port(a,b:in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
             cin: in std_logic;
             cout: out std_logic;
             s: out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0));         
    end component;
    component register is
        port( d: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
              clk, clear: in std_logic;
              q: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0));
    end component;
    COM: complement port map(B, compB);
    AA<= A(7) & A; --I'm extending A to 9-bit vector
    BB<= B(7) & B; --I'm extending B to 9-bit vector
    RCSUM: ripplecarry9bit port map (AA, BB, '0', SUM(9), SUM(8 downto 0));
    RCSUB: ripplecarry9bit port map (AA, compB, '0', SUB(9),SUB(8 downto 0));
    O<= SUM when C='1',
        SUB when C='0';
    R: register port map(O, clk, clear, OUT);
end E;
```

I'll explain my doubts. 
1) I don't know if `RCSUB: ripplecarry9bit port map (AA, compB, '0', SUB(9),SUB(8 downto 0));` is legit cause compA has the left bit as a sign and I don't know if for AA it's the same (it's not explicated in exercise structure).

2) 9-bit vector + 9-bit vector could give as output a 10-bit vector(I use this case as output) but could give as output a 9-bit vector, how can I manage this case in VHDL language?

Comment: Your code is chock full of syntax and semantic errors and doesn't all analyze. Your question(s) are also unclear- *(it's not explicated in exercise structure)*, you've neglected to show the table, what operation are you trying to implement in `exam`?

Comment: Why are you, as so many before you, building this from single bit adders then 8 bit adders then.... Is this a requirement in the assignment? It makes life for you (and us in checking) a thousand times more complex. The core of the solution can be written in about five lines of code.

Comment: @Oldfart yes, my teacher wants that we do all manually using the component like she explicated at lesson. can you give me an answer to my doubts?

@user1155120 you said: "Your code is chock full of syntax and semantic errors and doesn't all analyze" but you don't tell me where and what errors are... the table, that is based on the control signal C, logically is `C='0' OUT= A+B`; `C='1' OUT= A-B`.

Comment: you're not the only one in your school to search solutions here : possible duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50580896/1182849)

Comment: @grorel thanks but it's not the same, I solved that problem. here is different cause A != B. so shifing could not be applied! 
in my university there are 35k students :)